# The getSignaturesForAddress RPC request returns "Method not found"

Tags: rpc, validator, jsonrpc-api

I am trying to perform a simple API request against the local node that seems to be working fine but the response says "Method not found" even though the validator has the `--enable-cpi-and-log-storage --enable-rpc-transaction-history` command line arguments.

Request example:

```
curl http://node:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id": 1,"method": "getSignaturesForAddress","params": ["BopCMFbkTgug6uCpKpgebiXixnJ43ijNnvdUwDJUZ",{ "commitment": "finalized", "limit": 10}]}'
```

The response I'm getting:

```
[{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"},"id":1}]
```

What may be wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your payload (`-d`) wrapped in `[]`?

Comment: The wrapping in `[]` might be the issue, since some RPC nodes will forbid request batching.

Comment: Unfortunately, unwrapping didn't help, the response is still the same.

Comment: @Justabaka which version of the validator are you running? Could you post a dockerfile that reproduces this?